# How to show panorama image in image view

Tags: android, android-studio

I am beginner programmer in android,   how to show panorama image in image view in android studio. i search many link Panorama library is used on eclipse but i don't get how to implement it on android studio and also show panorama image in image view. please suggest me right way to implement this featured...

Answer (score 0):

[this is the library for panorama](https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/) read it hope it will help you

Comment: thanks hatib for replying. but actually i don't understand how to use this library in studio can you give me some source code example, so i get how to implement it on my project

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/wikis/UserGuide.wiki    this is the user guide for that library

Comment: Please accept the answer and if you also upvote my answer it would be great m glad it solved your problem